# How to get tangential velocity of revolving object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, rigid-bodies

So I have this empty game object which is rotating. Now this has a sphere object as its child. So when the parent point object rotates, the child sphere appears to be revolving around it. I want to know the velocity of that sphere, specifically, its tangential velocity.

When I debug, I find all the components of the sphere rigid body velocity/angular velocity to be (0,0,0). Can anyone please tell me how can I attain this..

Comment: Are you rotating the parent GameObject with physics (eg. `AddTorque()`), or manually by script (eg. Constantly updating `transform.rotation`)?

Comment: I am using `transform.RotateAround(Target.position, Target.up, _directionOfMovement * _speedWithoutInput * Time.deltaTime)` where I pass my parent point object as target

Comment: If you're using `transform.RotateAround()`, that means you're manipulating the transform directly, and not through physics. This means getting a velocity from the child's Rigidbody is not possible - you will have to manually calculate that using your knowledge of geometry/physics. However, it can be done if you give the parent a Rigidbody, and rotate it with physics (eg. [`Rigidbody.AddTorque()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html). Let me know if you want to take that approach instead.

Comment: Thanks..@Serlite..people seem to be suggesting the same thing..Actually I am new to unity..will try that..

Comment: All right. If you run into problems trying to set that up (can be a bit tricky for a new Unity user because of certain intricacies of the physics system), feel free to post another question and I'll be happy to post a solution guiding you through the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are rotating the object by manipulating its transform, the rigidbody isn't doing any work. Try rotating it using the rigidbody and you should see some velocity/angular velocity values.

Comment: Will try that..Thanks @Mikes3ds